# ¿Uso de la coma después de "que"?

Tags: gramática, puntuación

Leyendo el BOE, me he encontrado un "que" seguido de coma:

> España, como unidad política, es un Estado católico, social y
>   representativo, que, de acuerdo con su tradición, se declara
>   constituido en Reino.

Personalmente lo encuentro muy recargado, ¿pero tiene alguna función la coma después del "que"? Tal vez suena un poco menos literario:

> España, como unidad política, es un Estado católico, social y
>   representativo, que de acuerdo con su tradición, se declara
>   constituido en Reino.

Comment: A mí la que me sobra es la de antes. El resumen sería "España es un Estado que se declara constituido en Reino".

Comment: @Charlie si te sobra la coma de antes del *que* (estoy de acuerdo contigo) la frase quedaría: *España es un Estado católico, social y representativo que se declara constituido en Reino.*

Comment: @blonfu cierto, yo lo decía por resumir la frase a lo imprescindible. Me habría gustado elaborar a partir de ahí pero no encontré tiempo para montar una respuesta. Mi vida es un bendito caos. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En español no hay una regla que marque el uso de coma obligatorio después de `que`. Sin embargo, en el ejemplo que nos pones, estamos ante el uso de una **coma explicativa**.

Me refiero a los siguientes usos de la coma marcados en el Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas:

> A continuación se exponen los usos normativos de la coma.
>
> **1.1.1. Aposiciones explicativas:** Cuando llegó Adrián, el marido de mi hermana, todo se aclaró.
>
> **1.1.4. Cualquier otra clase de comentario, explicación o precisión a algo dicho:** Toda mi familia, incluido mi hermano, estaba de acuerdo; El buen gobernante, según sostenía un célebre político, debe estar siempre preparado para abandonar el poder.

Veamos tu ejemplo.

> España, como unidad política, es un Estado católico, social y representativo, que, de acuerdo con su tradición, se declara constituido en Reino.

Como ya mencioné arriba, **la coma está introduciendo una explicación** que no tiene vinculación sintáctica con el resto de la oración. En este caso, `de acuerdo con su tradición` es la aposición explicativa.

Sabemos que es una aposición explicativa sin vinculación con la oración principal porque podemos leer la oración sin la aposición y sigue siendo coherente:

> España, como unidad política, es un Estado católico, social y representativo, que se declara constituido en Reino.

Por esta razón (la coma introduce una explicación que no debería estar vinculada a la idea principal), desaconsejaría el uso de la coma como propones al final de tu pregunta.

---

Dato curioso: de hecho, sospecho que el único idioma con semejante regla (coma obligatoria después de `que`) es el ruso.

Comment: Cierto, estaba en la cuenta de que el "que" pertencía a la explicación (como cuando se introduce con un "which" en inglés), pero está claro que no es el caso. Entonces la que sí se podría quitar sería la coma anterior.

Comment: @jinawee estoy de acuerdo. La coma anterior podría retirarse.